Turn 3D wireframe into 2D projection with perspective NOT orthogonal
I am trying to convert Autocad 3DS Max 3D-coordinate information into a projection of 2D polygons in another graphic system (proprietary TGML format). This is to automate a rather tedious process of tracing out the projection by hand.
Orthogonal Image SuccessAs seen in the attached screenshot I have complete success with this using an orthogonal projection BUT this is not what I need for the end product. Perspective view is more lifelike/realistic. So I think this requires a focus point and FOV angle of say 45 degrees (adjustable).
Using 3DS Max MaxScript I am able to retrieve all the info I need for this transform: viewport location/rotation matrix, FOV, focal distance, vertex data for objects of interest. Now I just need to know where to find the math for this--basically some type of 3D skew transform.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
